# Time complexity for the nested loops in Python

Tags: python, string, time-complexity, nested-loops

I have the following code that checks if a string `s` contains the two first letters of a specific word (in lowercase and in any order):

```
def check_letters(input_string):

    word = 'Hello' # 1
    array_size = len(input_string) # 1

    for i in range (0, array_size): # n
        if input_string[i].lower()==word[0].lower(): # n
            for j in range (0, array_size): # n^2
                if input_string[j].lower()==word[1].lower(): # n^2
                    return True # 1

    return False # 1
```

I have commented out the complexity of each line and it seems that the worst-case complexity of my function is O(N^2) since a nested for loop has a complexity of O(N^2). Are the complexities of each line correct and is the worst-case complexity O(N^2)? Also, is the input size just the length of the string?

Comment: Yes, everything you state is correct. However you can perform the check in O(n)

Comment: there is some inconsistency in the notation. If you mean cumulative complexity, everything is correct except return statements. If comments reflect the complexity of only one statement, than `if`s should be O(1) and second loop is O(n). You're right that the overall complexity here is O(n^2)

Comment: also, optimal algorithm would do this in O(n+m), where n is the length of input string and m is the length of the word.

Comment: All of the `for-loops` and `if` conditionals is not very pythonic.  Convert `word` and `input_string` immediately with `lower`, use `list()` to convert `input_string` to a `list`, and replace everything else with `return (word[0] in input_list) & (word[1] in input_list)`.  I think the complexity is much less.